# Chrome Extension: how to detect that content script is already loaded into a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my background script:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeinfo, tab) {
    if (changeinfo.status !== 'complete')
        return;

    if (!matchesUrlFilters(tab.url))
        return;

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "enhance.js" });
    });
});
```

However, this seems to inject my content script twice in some cases (it might happen when `enhance.js` does `window.history.pushState`).

How can I fInd out whether the tab already has my content script? I tried `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` but it never called the callback if the content script was not yet added.

Comment: When the script gets injected twice do the two `enhance.js` scripts share a single execution environment with shared variables?

Comment: I do not know (and now probably will never check due to answer solving the problem completely).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I encountered this problem too. Instead of adding a check for the loaded script, I just had to remove the script from the "content_scripts" portion of my manifest.json since I am delegating the script's execution and do not want it loaded always.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: Updated per first comment on this answer.

You might try something like this.  Add a onRequest listener that will be used as a callback to load the scripts you want, but they will only load based on a value sent as part of the request message.  Then use executeScript to call "code" directly that sends a message with the value of a global variable (if it exists).

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeinfo, tab) {
    ...

    // execute a content script that immediately sends back a message 
    // that checks for the value of a global variable which is set when
    // the library has been loaded
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        code: "chrome.extension.sendRequest({ loaded: EnhanceLibIsLoaded || false });"
    });

    ...
});

// listen for requests
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(req, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (req.loaded === false) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "enhance.js" }, function() {
                // set the global variable that the scripts have been loaded
                // this could also be set as part of the enhance.js lib
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { code: "var EnhanceLibIsLoaded = true;" });
            });
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: This is genius, I modified it a bit (moved `onRequest.addListener` outside), but anyway it works perfectly. Note though that it should be `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` instead of `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, I edited the answer per your comments (let me know if I didn't get it right - or feel free to edit so it is).

Comment: I wanted to use this but there is an error in the consol saying : `Uncaught ReferenceError: EnhanceLibIsLoaded is not defined` :(

Comment: I got same problem as @Youhan above, even with the `isLoaded || false` check...I modified the injected code to: `"if(isLoaded){isLoaded=isLoaded}else{ var isLoaded=false;} chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...);"`

Comment: This worked for me in response for Uncaught reference error: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: "if (typeof(contentScriptIsLoaded) == 'undefined') contentScriptIsLoaded = false; chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ loaded: contentScriptIsLoaded });"
    });`