# How to Inject content script when page loads while having a popup page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to have my code to be injected using the content script method for google chrome extensions. This only works when my manifest does not have a Popup page and my background.html has this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_script.js" });
});
});
```

How can I have this code be triggered every time a new page has been loaded in chrome while having a PoPup page? because so far the only way that it works is when I click the browser action button of the extension.

Also in my content script section of manifest I have included all this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{

"matches": ["http://jquery.com/*"],
"all_frames":true,
  "js": ["jquery.js","jquery-ui.min.js","content_script.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` instead of `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` from the background page to load the content script every time the page is updated.

**Long answer:** You **CAN** in fact have a content script be loaded when their is a popup page, either by including the content script from the manifest or using programmatic injection from the background page (as you suggested in your question).

### From the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://myurl.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
     "http://myurl.com/*",
     "tabs"
  ],
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
     "popup": "popup.html"
  }
  ...
}
```

Make sure the "matches" property matches the URL for the page you want to load the content script on.

### Using programmatic injection:

You can use the way you suggested in your question, which will insert the content script when the browser action is clicked **OR** you could do it every time the browser URL is updated like so:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content_script.js" });
  });   
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved all my problems! the only issue now is that the executeScript gets called multiple times is there any way to avoid this? Im guessing the onUpdated is called several times on a page while it loads?

Comment: Actually nevermind I tried the matches in the manifest and I put "http://*/*" for the matches and it worked even without the programmatic injection!

Comment: You can determine if a script has already loaded when using programmatic injection, but it is a little more tricky, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8860891/646585