# Content Script injection in web site popup window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my extension, content scripts are well injected into the page when the URL of the updated tab starts to match what I defined in the manifest.json.

However, if the site is opening a popup windows, my content scripts are not injected whereas the URL still matches what is defined in the manifest. I could inject the scripts only programmatically using executeScript on the newly created popup window and tab.

Is this the normal way of doing it? I would have excepted that content scripts are injected whatever the type of window based on the config in the manifest...

Thanks if you can help,
Christophe

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965953/how-to-inject-content-script-when-page-loads-while-having-a-popup-page

Comment: Shame on me, I forgot the "*" at the end of my URL in the matches element of the manifest (was : `http://myurl.com/` and should be `http://myurl.com/*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the "*" at the end of my URL in the matches element of the manifest (was : `http://myurl.com/` and should be `http://myurl.com/*`)